# How do I rewrite “The doctor has just finished his shift” using “yet”?

Tags: sentence-construction, exam-questions

> Rewrite the following sentence using the word in brackets to give the same meaning.
> The doctor has just finished his shift. ***(yet)***

I learned that yet usually comes with negative, like "The doctor didn't finish his shift yet.", but in this, I didn't find a way but to add something to sentence like:

> The doctor has just finished his shift but didn't leave yet.

Is that the correct way to include "yet" in that sentence?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no more On Topic here [than it was on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558326/how-do-i-rewrite-the-doctor-has-just-finished-his-shift-using-yet)

Comment: I thought they refered me to post it here. 
Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting answers.

Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Closed 2 hours ago.

(Private feedback for you)

Comment: Welcome to ELL - yes, this is a better place to ask these sorts of questions. I've edited your question to fix a number of punctuation errors. Your questions will get a better response if they are properly punctuated and capitalized. That makes them easier to understand. You might want to [edit] your question to explain why you think your idea isn't correct. Understanding your doubts can help someone write a more helpful answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I don't think this question is unsalvageable. What would be your advice on how it could be brought on topic? Stating it was closed on EL&U doesn't help the author figure out how they can write a better question.

Comment: @ColleenV: When I closevoted this on ELU, there was just the answer saying **It's impossible** (what the OP is being asked to do). Since then, I see there's been [further comment.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/558326/how-do-i-rewrite-the-doctor-has-just-finished-his-shift-using-yet#comment1377375_558326) But I still can't see any way to make sense of the question - even allowing for the possibility that the test-setter is very bad at English, I can't see what they were getting at. And the OP hasn't got a clue, obviously.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica That's a lot more helpful explanation of why you're voting to close it than "I'm closing this because it was closed at EL&U".

Comment: Actually, the question has now been changed so much my closevote seems pointless. So I'll retract it, and not bother thinking about whether the revised (=totally different) question  is effectively ProofReading (I can only closevote once, so I don't want to upset myself by deciding I really want to do something that I know I can't! :)

Comment: @amr ahmed - the "negation" is ***implied*** in your example, by the use of the "contrastive / refutative" conjunction ***BUT***.

Comment: "Has the doctor finished his shift yet?" "Yes, just." // I honestly can't think of another way to do it. I agree with @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica it's an awful question (that amr was asked to do, the question he asked was fine — I'd be baffled and want help too!).

Comment: One context where ***just yet*** occurs naturally would be *"Please, teacher! Can I go to the toilet?" "**Not just yet, Timmy**. Wait until the end of the lesson."* But I don't see how that helps here.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Fumbles that the person who wrote the question should be shot, but that does not seem to me to call for rejecting the student's question. The student should not be blamed for the errors of the teacher.

There is no way, in my opinion, that the sentence asked about can be revised idiomatically to express exactly the same meaning by inserting the word "yet."

The best that I can do, and I have been writing for a long time, is to use some stilted or dated expression such as

> Yet a moment ago, the doctor was still on shift.

It is a stupid exercise, but not a stupid question.

Comment: I never intended any criticism of the OP for asking the question. If there hadn't already been an answer on ELU saying **It's impossible**, I'd have pointed that out to the OP myself while closevoting [the original, significantly different] question over on ELU. But have an upvote for effectively saying the same thing here.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested sentence

> The doctor has just finished his shift but didn't leave yet.

does include the word 'yet' but it  adds more information, so could be argued that it doesn't have the same meaning. I'd also write it as

> The doctor has just finished his shift but hasn't left yet.

so all the tenses agree.

The only way I can think of to re-write it is:

> "Has the doctor finished his shift yet?"
> "Yes, just."

but that seems unnecessarily complicated, and isn't a single sentence any more.

I think it's a poorly written question, and would be interested to know what the correct answer is supposed to be!